# Bootstrap multiple inputs two lines

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I create a multiple input with checkbox on the left and two lines each one with an .

Here´s the code that I´m using:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" id="idays">
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="days1" disabled="" maxlength="10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="days2" disabled="" maxlength="10">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And I want something similar to this:

[two inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1KZl.jpg)

Comment: Bootstrap flex will achieve this very easily: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="col-11 pl-0">
      <div class"row">
        <div class="col-12">Option 1</div>
        <div class="col-12">Option 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```